# assign derivative to function in Maple

Tags: maple

I have a situation in Maple, where a large expression is calculated.  In that expression a derivative appears, say $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t)$$.  I know the function 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t)$$ 
but I do not know the function f (and integrating makes the problem excessively difficult, it is not worth to explain the details).  Here is my question:  how can I get maple to replace $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t)$$ with my known function?  A naive assignment such as 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t):= expression$$
does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is using the subs command 
https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=subs

such as 
subs( $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t)$$=known function, expression)